# In chrome bookmark bar, is there a mechanism or extension to "symbolic link" to a bookmark folder?

Tags: google-chrome, symbolic-link, bookmarks

I've experimented with various structures for my bookmarks bar and found that shallow trees work much better for me.  To that end my top level bookmarks bar is filled with short names with more descriptive longer names used below that the top level.  It would be very useful to be able to create symbolic links with short names to longer named folders below the top level.  Often I work more on a few topic areas that normally are one to levels deep but I temporarily need to access them hundreds of times a day.  Navigating then consumes an inordinate amount of time.  Moving them up to the top level requires shortening the names and later then remembering to move them back in the hierarchal structure with their old full name.  A symbolic link mechanism would solve this problem.

If there is a way to do this with a bookmarket, I have not discovered how such is done.  Of course, that might be because I have little knowledge of Javascript.

Thanks